# iOS Download Custom Push Notification Sounds

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

So I've implemented push notifications with custom sounds in my app.

And my app plays those with the push notification with no problem.

My question is is it possible to download custom sounds after the app has been installed and play them with the custom push notification system?

Since they should be present in the main bundle and that's read only - is there another way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.

As far as my reading of the documentation goes, the sound files must be inside the read-only main bundle, like you said.